# is there a parameter accelerates Sybase insertion

Tags: java, database, jdbc, sybase

I am using Sybase ASE, and for a table, in which I will save results calculated by Java. This table has 10 columns, one column type is `INT` value (but not an ID column), and other 9 columns are all `VARCHAR(50)` type.

There's no index or trigger on this table (in fact this table is really independent). I need to insert around 160K rows into this table. I tried to separate the work by batch, which will do 10,000 insertions every time. I used two different ways, one is Spring's `JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate` the other one is native JDBC `PreparedStatement.executeBatch` api.

However no clear winner regarding the performance. Both of them takes around 25 to 30 seconds for 10K insertions.

Then I thought it could be related to the JDBC driver, so I tried two different drivers: jConnect and jTDS. No real impact on insertion performance.

Finally I decided to compare Sybase with another database, i.e. PostgreSQL in my test. I kept the same Java code, and surprisingly PostgreSQL takes only 0.3 second for every 10K insertions, while Sybase took 25 to 30 seconds (75 to 100 times longer).

DBA support team explains the difference is due to that PostgreSQL is installed on my local machine, while Sybase is installed on our enterprise's server. However, I am not convinced by this explanation at all.

Does anyone know if there's a configuration in Sybase which could considerably impact the insertion speed? Or are there any other possible causes for my above scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The delay that you see on the sybase end is because of a lot of factors that needs to be checked and comparing it to a different database that too on a local machine is not correct.

For starting, we need to check the network latency and the storage used in the sybase database. We need to check the sybase server configuration, page size and locking scheme of the table that you are inserting into. We also need to do a basic health check of the server while you are inserting the data. As you have mentioned that you have used two different ways to insert the data, It is important that you check whether these two ways along are updated accordingly to the sybase client you have installed on your system.

To sum it up, It may be a simple issue as blocking on the sybase instance or it could be related to the storage which is not able to write it quickly. Given the sybase is configured properly, The performance would be very good.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the DB server is local or not may indeed make a significant difference. Until you cut out this factor, comparison with a local DB makes little sense.

But that aside, there are many aspects that affect insert performance in ASE.  First off, make sure the overall memory configuration (e.g. data cache and procedure cache) is not too small -- leaving it at the installation defaults is a guarantee for disappointing results. Then there is network packet size that can play a role. And the batch size (#rows before you commit). And the table's lock scheme.
Trying to use minimally logged inserts will help (requires config setting changes), especially since the table has no indexes (and no UNIQUE or PK constraints either?)
The ASE server page size (which you choose when you create the server) also makes a difference: bigger is basically better for inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ENABLE_BULK_LOAD` parameter to `True`. It will speed it up.